# Apps Script to Append data AND add date dd-MM-yyyy format

Tags: google-apps-script, append

I am trying to combine two Apps Scripts.

Append data - this works fine and adds data according to a time frame

```
function appendOvertime() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var reportSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Weekly Numbers");
  var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Append Data")
  var reportData = reportSheet.getRange("A2:O25")
                              .getValues();
  var lastRow = recordsSheet.getLastRow();
  //copy data
  recordsSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2, 24, 15)
              .setValues(reportData);
}
```

Add date - this works for the google sheet I have created to test it.

```
var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1';
var DATETIME_HEADER = 'datetime';

function getDatetimeCol(){
  var headers = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues().shift();
  var colindex = headers.indexOf(DATETIME_HEADER);
  return colindex+1;
}

function onEdit(e) {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var datecell = ss.getRange(cell.getRowIndex(), getDatetimeCol());
  if (ss.getName() == SHEET_NAME && cell.getColumn() == 1 && !cell.isBlank() && datecell.isBlank()) {      
  datecell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
}
```

I want the date script to run after the data has been appended in the sheet called "Append Data" and for the date to be placed in Column A - which has the column header "Date"

I am new to apps script so would appreciate any help anyone can offer.  Thanks

I can get the scripts to work independently
I cannot get the date placed in a column before where edits are being made i.e. add data to B but date in A

Answer (score 0):

> I want the date script to run after the data has been appended in the sheet called "Append Data" and for the date to be placed in Column A - which has the column header "Date"

One way to do that is to put the necessary code at the end of `appendOvertime()`, like this:

```js
function appendOvertime() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const reportData = ss.getRange('Weekly Numbers!A2:O25').getValues();
  const recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Append Data')
  const appended = appendRows_(recordsSheet, reportData, 2);
  recordsSheet.getRange(appended.rowStart, 1, appended.numRows, 1)
    .setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
}
```

For that to work, you will need to paste the [`appendRows_()`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/269219) and `getLastRow_()` utility functions in your script project.